# bash: "fill in the blank" alias that allows further typing

Tags: bash, alias

**Background:**

A well-known feature of bash is the "alias" command.

It allows the user to save keystrokes by "abbreviating" frequently-used or annoying-to-type commands and executing them as if the user had typed in the entire command herself and hit ENTER at the bash prompt.

**Problem:**

The alias command automatically executes the command that corresponds to the alias immediately after the alias has been entered by the user. But there may be times when the user does not want this behavior.

**Question:**

Is there a way in bash to create "fill-in-the-blank" alias commands? This would be an alias that does not automatically run the command after hitting ENTER, but instead gives the user the chance to type an argument.

**Pitfalls to avoid:**

**Ruled out reverse-i-search:** The "reverse-i-search" feature of bash supports this "fill-in-the-blank" functionality request, but it (apparently) does not allow the user to specify commands ahead of time, instead only searching through the history. This may not be the desired behavior.

**Ruled out functions** The use of bash functions could meet this functionality request, however this may not be the desired solution because the user may have reasons for not wanting to create a function.

Comment: No. Aliases are deprecated in favor of functions. If you have reasons not to use functions, then perhaps `bash` is not the right tool for you.

Comment: Can you clarify you question? I'm struggling to understand what you're trying to do

Comment: If there exists a defensible reason for using an alias instead of a function, I would love to be enlightened.

Comment: @Fuzzyfelt: Step1: create an alias mycd="cd /some/long/path"; Step2: run the alias and notice it behaves as expected; Step3: Find a way to create the *same* alias, except that it allows the user to fill-in-the-blank before actually executing the command (e.g., alias mycd="cd _fill_in_the_blank") ... that is the basic goal, but without using bash functions.

Comment: @chepner: this is a search for alternative approaches, if there are none, that's fine, but the question is out there for the SO community, rationales aside for now.

Comment: @dreftymac Aliases already let you append arguments like your describe. `alias mycd=cd` and then `mycd /some/path` will execute `cd /some/path`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Ruled out reverse-i-search

Use this, then when you find correct match, hit <kbd>Esc</kbd>. This will allow you to edit the command before running.

Comment: thanks for the reply. The problem with this approach is that reverse-i-search only works with commands that are already in your command history.

Possible to suggest a way to use this that does not require the command to already be in your search history? That's what the original question is wrestling with.

Answer (score 2):

On second (and third and fourth) reading, I think you are looking for the `readline` function `alias-expand-line`. It's not bound to any key by default, but the more general `shell-expand-line` is pre-bound to <kbd>Meta</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd>. Type a command line, and press that instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and the current command line is expanded by the shell, but not executed.

If you don't want the full expansion (parameters, history, etc) but just aliases, you can use the `bind` command to bind <kbd>Meta</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd> (or some other key combination) to `alias-expand-line`, which should expand only aliases.

Once expanded, you can edit the line as desired, or even use <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd> to open the current command line in `$EDITOR` for more extensive editing.